# Can I retrain my keras model on small dataset with some empty folders

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras

I am working on a vehicle classification problem.

I trained my model with 605 labels(folders) and 300k photos.

After testing my trained model, I checked my wrong answers' training and validation photos. I realized some of my labels training or validation photos are wrong or not enough different from another.

I can prepare a small dataset that only contains these wrong learnt labels photos and keep other labels folders empty.

If i retrain my model, will I get better accuracy? Or should I train from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting is to fine tune the network giving it a portion of the starting data set?

If yes, well you can try, but I am not sure what the outcome would be. But remember to keep a train and test set separated!